# Grails Rest CRUD

Tags: rest, grails, crud

I'v been trying to make my website work with rest, but i find it a little bit tricky. I followed this tutorial:

http://www.suryasuravarapu.com/2009/06/rest-crud-with-grails.html

And i managed to do the 'customer' and 'customer/1' get request in the WizTools RestClient. However, the 'update', 'create' and 'delete' part i didnt, meaning 'put', 'post' and 'delete'. My question is:

- How can i try this three methods, what do i need to do (folowwing the example)?

Thanks in advanced,
Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking how you can test these methods, you can use any REST client. If you have Chromium (or Google Chrome), [Advanced REST client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ahdjpgllmllekelefacdedbjnjaplfjn) is a good one. Mozilla Firefox equivalent is [Poster](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/poster/). In the tutorial you are pointing, a [standalone REST client](http://code.google.com/p/rest-client/) (written in Java) is suggested.

Once you have started one of these clients, you should be able to send requests using PUT, POST, DELETE, or even one of the [other, less common HTTP methods](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/Methods.html). Just put the XML in the *body* part of your REST client, set a header called `Content-Type` to `text/xml` and send the request (by clicking on the green arrows on the right of the address bar).

Comment: ok. so please give me an example of code i could do to perform a 'post' to the server.

Comment: You don't need to write code (except for the XML of the request). Just select the PUT method in the REST client, set the body field to `<customer>...</customer>` as in the example, and send the request.

Comment: or just download SoapUI which also handles RESTful API's http://www.soapui.org/REST-Testing/getting-started.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking about a client that can help you try out the POST and PUT methods, correct? If so you can try out a very handy POSTER plugin for firefox. It will let you use your FF browser to test POST, PUT, DELETE methods:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/poster/

Comment: no. for that i can use the program i refered. What i mean is, i don't know the basics about 'post' and 'put'. I don't know what i need to send to the server to perform that tasks

Comment: If you are following example than the DELETE method just takes a regular id parameter like so id=1. The UPDATE requires an id parameter just like DELETE and also an XML snippet that the example shows in this image:  http://www.suryasuravarapu.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/06/crudgrails-create.jpg